# Inserting Records into a sorted csv file through php code

Tags: php, sorting, csv

I am using php to sort records from a csv file based on a key value. I have 1584 records in a csv file. After reading each record I am sorting all the records in descending order based upon a key value. When I am writing the sorted array only 792(half of 1584) records are getting inserted. Is there any limit for entering maximum number of records that we can append to a csv file through php code. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$handle=fopen("entiredata1.csv","r");
$i=0;
while($record=fgetcsv($handle,250))
{
      $list[$i]=$record;
      $i=$i+1;
}
fclose($handle);
$j=$i;

echo "j=$j <br>";
echo "i=$i <br>";

for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++)
{
   for($k=0;$k<$i;$k++)
   {
        if($list[$i][12] > $list[$k][12])
        {
            $temp=$list[$i];
            $list[$i]=$list[$k];
            $list[$k]=$temp;
        }
   }
}

$whandle=fopen("sorted.csv","a");
for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++)
{          
      fputcsv($whandle,$list[$i]);
      $i=$i+1;
}
fclose($whandle);  
?>
```

Comment: What does your output show? Particularly this line: `echo "j=$j <br>";`

Comment: in the output, should this: `for($i=0; $i<$j; $i++)` be something similar to: `for($i=0; $i < count($list); $i++)`? i.e. the number of elements in the array

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code is working fine. I just had to restart my system.